# Solar panel simulation for 7 solar cells in series

Tags: voltage, power, voltage-regulator, current-source

I have this question about the circuit that I am working on for quite long and it is just not working. Please help, i have already tried every thing i could understand.

I followed a YouTube tutorial and the circuit is working fine for the inputs entered in the video but not working for my modified inputs. i will attach the snapshots of Youtube tutorial below and my input values are mentioned here:

VOC=2.33V,
Short ckt current Isc=500mA=0.5A,
No.of cells in series = 7.

I want to obtain the maximum power curve for the given conditions. But I am getting power only in few mW that should not be like this... please suggest what changes should I make in circuit. The
subcircuit is of a single cell and  the main circuit is for series connected cells.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z2C28OXu4xA&t=617s

p.s. also if you can explain the purpose of .param IS=1nA . What does this current mean and why is it needed, why are there 2 current supplies, 1nA in main circuit and 5A in sub circuit?

here is the link of youtube tutorial, i followed.

[image: sub circuit for a single cell.]

[image: main circuit for panel]

Comment: The video explains everything. Have patience and don't skip. If you still don't understand, then you don't know the basics, in which case I'd suggest learning more before tackling more advanced topics.

Comment: i got the working but i can't have the desired output for my input values

Comment: What values have you tried and what results did you get that make you say they're not what you expected?